# How i set body overflow hidden when some class called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to set body overflow to hidden when "popup" class was used. And called this class by JavaScript. As my CSS it don't work.
Can i have "body" tag nested in my class like this?

```
#CSS
.popup {
    display: table;
    height: 100% !important;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 400;
    body {
        overflow: hidden!important;
    }
}
```

My example is when you click on Facebook photos, it will appear to full screen and locked scrolling. Thanks all helps

I call it like this.

```
<a href="#" onclick="getphoto(int)">Click to view larger</a>
```

JavaScript

```
function getphoto(inputString) {
        $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
        if(inputString.length == 0||false) {
             $('#suggestions3').fadeOut(); // Hide the suggestions box
        }else{
     //alert(inputString);
        $.post("p/photo.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data) { // Do an AJAX call
        $('#suggestions3').fadeIn(); // Show the suggestions box
        $('#suggestions3').html(data); // Fill the suggestions box
    });
}
}
```

inputString is photo id. 
In photo.php it return html content `<div class="popup">...my content...</div>`

Comment: "Can i have "body" tag nested in my class like this?" NO.

Comment: When and How your `popup` class was used?

Comment: Thanks everyone It worked when i add `$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');` to getphoto function

Comment: Yes, it worked but scrolling is not visible. how to do it visible but locked it like Facebook photo viewer

Comment: @brendan try `$("body").css("overflow", "auto");`

Answer (score 3):

*Can i have "body" tag nested in my class like this?* No.

When `popup` class is called, use jQuery `.css()` this way:

```
$("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
```

More Info: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `CSS` like that. You can however have a class called `overflow-hidden` in your css which just sits like this:

```
.overflow-hidden{
    overflow:hidden !important;
}
```

Then in jQuery:

```
$('.popup').click(function(){
    $('body').addClass('overflow-hidden');
});
```

You can also use

```
toggleClass()
```

and

```
removeClass()
```

so you can `addClass()` when you want to give it the css class then `removeClass()` once the popup has gone.

Comment: It's not a best practice to name your class just as the CSS properties it contains (think about how many `.red` are blue...). Also I doubt of your `toggleClass` functionality, better use `addClass` and `removeClass` when needed.

Comment: @EdgarGriñant The `overflow-hidden` class was just an example, obviously he can name it what he wants. And yes, `addClass` and `removeClass` are probably best suited for this, I'll edit my answer to use that primarily thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No  , you cant use css like that

```
if($('.popup').is(':visible')){

 $("body").css('overflow', 'hidden');

}
```

or

```
$('.popup').click(function(){
  $("body").css('overflow', 'hidden');
});
```

On close of your popup or else condition

```
 $("body").css('overflow', 'yourchoice');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery like this:

```
$('body').filter(function(){
  return $(this).find('.popup').is(':visible')
}).css('overflow','hidden');
```

---

You can't use nested css like in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addClass` and `removeClass` in your jquery

```
.bodyOverflow() { 
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

And in jquery

```
$('.popup').on('click', function(){
   $('body').addClass('bodyOverflow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/pwzaT/

#### JQUERY

```
$('button#show').on('click', function(){
    $('.popup').fadeIn(300);
    $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
});
$('button#hide').on('click', function(){
    $('.popup').fadeOut(300);
    $('body').css('overflow','auto');
});
```