# set body to overflow hidden when div is called

Tags: jquery, css

I have an on click function that hides and shows a div.

When the div is clicked I want the body to have `overflow: hidden;` - this works, but when I close the div the "body" still has `overflow: hidden;`, but I want it to be `overflow: scroll;`

Can you help me?

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723076/how-i-set-body-overflow-hidden-when-some-class-called) but havent managed to fix it.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".headeropen").hide();
    $(".headerclosed").show();

    $('.headerclosed').click(function() {
        $(".headeropen").slideToggle();
        $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    });
});
```

Comment: slideToggle simply opens the item if it is closed and closes it if it is open. Whereas the first time you click .headerclosed it merely sets the body to overflow hidden (there is no toggle). I think the best method would be to have a simple class with the overflow property and then use toggleClass. I can write that in an answer if it helps, I think it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably overkill, but I wrote this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/qjmnakkc/

JS:

```
$('.headerclosed').click(function(){
    $(".headeropen").slideToggle();
    $('body').toggleClass('hiddenOverflow');
});
```

CSS:

```
body {
    overflow:scroll;
}

.hiddenOverflow {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback function. `400` is the default speed for slideToggle, and `swing` is default for easing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".headeropen").hide();
    $(".headerclosed").show();

    $('.headerclosed').click(function() {
       $(".headeropen").slideToggle(400, 'swing', function(){
            if($('body').css('overflow') == 'scroll' || $('body').css('overflow') == 'auto'){
                $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
            }else{
                $('body').css('overflow','scroll');
            }
        });
    });
});
```